# How to pass command line arguments to kotlin springboot

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, command-line, command-line-arguments

I made a proof of concept application using [Spring Initilizr](https://start.spring.io/), making an application with Kotlin, Spring Boot, and Gradle. I'm trying to make a CLI application, and having trouble with my `bootRun` command to add arguments that my application can consume.

So far, I have tried to do a simple print of the array of arguments in my program.

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    println("starting application")
//  SpringApplication.run(GeocodingAuditApplication::class.java, *args)
    println(args.size)
    for(arg in args){
        println(arg)
    }
    println("done")
}
```

But when I try to pass in any arguments with a `--`, then gradle assumes that it is a build task argument, and I receive an error.

I've also tried passing in as a `-Pargs`

> ./gradlew bootRun -Pargs=--hello=true

However, this isn't getting through. My println for the size of my args still returns 0.

How can I pass in a ./gradlew CLI command to run and still pass in command line arguments?

Answer (score 0):

For Gradle, the correct way to pass an argument is simply through the `--args` tag, and the arguments to be passed through need to be in quotation marks

> ./gradlew bootRun --args="name=bob"